# CI PHP: How to hold data in Array while using double Foreach Loop and turn it json encode?

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter, foreach

I wanna get data from two table with no relation, i using foreach to fetch all data by selected key and gather data from two table into array. How do i hold data in array while i fetch two table using foreach? im using Codeigniter framework.
here is the code:

```
$price = $this->pricing->get_by($hc); //get from pricing
foreach ($price as $ps){
   $promo = $this->discount->get_by($ps['key1'],$ps['key2']); //get from discount
   foreach ($promo as $k) {
      if ($k['keyA']!='percent') {
         $pricing = $ps['key3'] - $k['keyB'];   
         $data = array(
            'room_code'=>$ps['key1'],
            'price_code'=>$ps['key2'],
            'price'=>$ps['key3'],
            'discount_type'=>$k['keyA'],
            'disc'=>$k['keyB'],
            'finalprice'=>$pricing
          );
       } 
       elseif ($k['keyA']=='percent') {
          $pricing = $ps['key3'] - ($ps['key3'] * $k['keyB']/100);
          $data = array(
            'room_code'=>$ps['key1'],
            'price_code'=>$ps['key2'],
            'price'=>$ps['key3'],
            'discount_type'=>$k['keyA'],
            'disc'=>$k['keyB'],
            'finalprice'=>$pricing
          );                                
       }    
     print_r($data);
     // echo json_encode($data);
     }
}
```

And i get the relust like this:

```
Array
(
[room_code] => 1212    
[price_code] => P1
[price] => 500
[discount_type] => amount
[disc] => 20
[finalprice] => 480
)
Array
(
[room_code] => 1213
[price_code] => P2
[price] => 500
[discount_type] => percent
[disc] => 50
[finalprice] => 250
)
```

If i turn json the result like this:

```
{"room_code":"1212","price_code":"P1","price":"500","discount_type":"amount","disc":"20","finalprice":480}{"room_code":"1213","price_code":"P2","price":"500","discount_type":"percent","disc":"50","finalprice":250}
```

This is not valid json format, so please help..

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: If you print a json_encode inside the loop, it will produce a json object. that means you will get multiple json object as the output, without an outer key value pair

Comment: @M.Hemant i ecpected like this when turn into json format

[
{"room_code":"1212","price_code":"P1","price":"500","discount_type":"ammount","disc":"20","finalprice":480},
{"room_code":"1213","price_code":"P2","price":"500","discount_type":"percent","disc":"50","finalprice":250}
]

Comment: Try adding a `$result = []` at the begining and push the `$data` to the `$result` at the print_r line and then add the `echo json_encode($result)` to the end.

Comment: @AdarshMohan if i print out of looping i just get 1 value at the end of key value looping, how to get all value at outside looping?

Comment: Push them while inside the loop, and print the final array at the end

Comment: Thank u guys already solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$price = $this->pricing->get_by($hc); //get from pricing
$data_arr = array();
foreach ($price as $ps){
   $promo = $this->discount->get_by($ps['key1'],$ps['key2']); //get from discount
   foreach ($promo as $k) {
      if ($k['keyA']!='percent') {
         $pricing = $ps['key3'] - $k['keyB'];   
         $data = array(
            'room_code'=>$ps['key1'],
            'price_code'=>$ps['key2'],
            'price'=>$ps['key3'],
            'discount_type'=>$k['keyA'],
            'disc'=>$k['keyB'],
            'finalprice'=>$pricing
          );
       } 
       elseif ($k['keyA']=='percent') {
          $pricing = $ps['key3'] - ($ps['key3'] * $k['keyB']/100);
          $data = array(
            'room_code'=>$ps['key1'],
            'price_code'=>$ps['key2'],
            'price'=>$ps['key3'],
            'discount_type'=>$k['keyA'],
            'disc'=>$k['keyB'],
            'finalprice'=>$pricing
          );                                
       }    
       $data_arr[] = $data;
     }
}

echo json_encode($data_arr);
```

The result should be a valid JSON array:

```
[{"room_code":"1212","price_code":"P1","price":"500","discount_type":"amount","disc":"20","finalprice":480},{"room_code":"1213","price_code":"P2","price":"500","discount_type":"percent","disc":"50","finalprice":250}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,
your $data is overlapping so I just converted it to an array so all data will get stored in it.

```
$price = $this->pricing->get_by($hc); //get from pricing
$mainData = array();
foreach ($price as $ps){
   $promo = $this->discount->get_by($ps['key1'],$ps['key2']); //get from discount
 if(!empty($promo)){
   foreach ($promo as $k) {
      if ($k['keyA']!='percent') {
         $pricing = $ps['key3'] - $k['keyB'];   
         $data = array(
            'room_code'=>$ps['key1'],
            'price_code'=>$ps['key2'],
            'price'=>$ps['key3'],
            'discount_type'=>$k['keyA'],
            'disc'=>$k['keyB'],
            'finalprice'=>$pricing
          );
       } 
       elseif ($k['keyA']=='percent') {
          $price = $ps['key3'] - ($ps['key3'] * $k['keyB']/100);
          $data = array(
            'room_code'=>$ps['key1'],
            'price_code'=>$ps['key2'],
            'price'=>$ps['key3'],
            'discount_type'=>$k['keyA'],
            'disc'=>$k['keyB'],
            'finalprice'=>$pricing
          );                                
       }
       array_push($mainData,$data);    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will not work as it will print a growing array as the output on each loop.

Comment: @AdarshMohan Is it Correct Now?

Comment: the issue already solved by @Koala_Yeung, and thank u for ur help